# removing an item from a datacollection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

when i remove an item from dataCollection using RemoveAt(index) it's removed, but when i try to remove another item in the list the item is not removed
i do have a listBox that has ListBoxElementsin it and the data is set to it using datacollection binding ..... so when i need to remove an item i remove it from the datacollection and the view is refreshed automatically, but when i try to remove another item after it, the view still the same and the item is not removed

```
DataCollection2.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: Have you tried using ObservableCollection? What type is your DataCollection? Can you edit your answer and add more code?

Comment: i'm already using ObservableCollection

Comment: Can you check in debug mode how your Datacollection looks like after every RemoveAt?

Answer (score 0):

When using binding, make sure you call the OnPropertyChange event, passing it the name of the changed property (in your case, "DataCollection2").